# Cannot access public field on public inner class

Tags: java, class, field, public

I have the following test code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main() {
    int А = new Main2().А;
    System.out.println(А);
}

public class Main2 {
    public int A = 0;
}
```

}

When ran I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
А cannot be resolved or is not a field

at Main.<init>(Main.java:10)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Why can I not access Main2.A() from its outter class?

Answer (score 4):

The `A` character in

```
int А = new Main2().А;
```

is not a UTF-8 character, and is not the same as the one used in the variable name in the `Main2` class. Copy-paste the `A` from the inner class and use that. It will compile.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        Main2 m = new Main2();
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(m.A));
    }

    class Main2 {
        public int A;
        public Main2() {
            A = 0;
        }
    }
}
```